# XSLT: Current date time long fromat with millisecond

Tags: xslt

I have upgraded XSLT processor. And getting the current date time. But it is not in desired format.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Y,4][D,2][M,2] [H]:[m]:[s]:[f01] [Z]')" />
```

gives

```
20132409 14:03:17:54 -04:00
```

But I want in long format with milliseconds. Something like 1346498794643

Comment: There's no standard function to do this in XSLT/XPath version 1.0.  Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: It was 1.0 which changed to 2.0. But it didn't work after that. I tried removing reference of xp20 but still no luck.

Comment: Ian asked for the XSLT processor you use, not the XSLT version. An XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 will support the function `current-dateTime`, an XSLT 1.0 processor like Saxon 6 or Xalan will not.

Comment: @MartinHonnen My bad. I am new to XSLT. `xsl:vendor` gave me `Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC)`.

Comment: If you use Java and want to use XSLT 2.0 then I would suggest to try Saxon 9 instead of Xalan. It is available in an open source version "HE" on http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ and in commercial versions ("PE", "EE") from http://www.saxonica.com/.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated it and getting the current data time in wrong format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I've remembered the epoch correctly:

```
T:\ftemp>xslt2 milliseconds.xsl milliseconds.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>1380039731273
T:\ftemp>type milliseconds.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="( current-dateTime() -
                          xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') )
                        div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S') * 1000"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
T:\ftemp>
```

Recall that in XSLT the current date and time is a static value for the duration of the transformation.  You will get the same value for every time you invoke this function in a single invocation of a given stylesheet.